# JQuery - Obviate the Need for Replacement Element for Hover Function on Nav. Bar

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I'd like to understand if the problem in the code snippet below regards attempting to execute a fadeOut on a none-existent navigation bar element, and if so, how to retain this bar using a comparable code structure.  As shown below, the element fades out as expected using fadeOut, but does not fade in using fadeIn.  When observing the HTML in firebug, the fadeOut event concludes with "Display: none".

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    $(".page-scroll a#textAnimated.navbar-brand.page-scroll     
    span.brand").stop().animate({'font-size': '20px'}, 'fast');
    //$(".page-scroll").stop().fadeIn(50);
    $("a.page-scroll").stop().animate({'font-size': '16px'}, 'fast');



} else {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    $(".page-scroll a#textAnimated.navbar-brand.page-scroll 
    span.brand").stop().animate({'font-size': '26px'}, 'slow');
    $("a.page-scroll").stop().animate({'font-size': '18px'},   
    'fast');                   

 }});
```

Problem appears to lie herein:

```
**$(document).ready(function(){
$("nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top").hover(

    function(){
        $(this).stop(true, true).fadeIn('400');}, 
    function(){
        $(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut('100');}
);
});**



//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
.navbar {
    padding: 20px 0;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top {
    display:inherit;
}





.top-nav-collapse {
    padding: 0;
}
}

.intro-section {
height: 100%;
padding-top: 150px;
text-align: center;
background: #fff;
}

.resume-section {
height: 100%;
padding-top: 150px;
text-align: center;
background: #eee;
}

.aboutme-section {
height: 100%;
padding-top: 150px;
text-align: center;
background: #fff;
}

.contact-section {
height: 100%;
padding-top: 150px;
text-align: center;
background: #eee;
}

html {
      background-image: url("images/polygBg.png");
      background-size: 100%;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    body  {
      width: 80%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: .985;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, .7);
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 0px;        
      font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
      overflow-y:scroll;
    }
    body a {
      font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    .container {
      width: 85%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 0px;        
      font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    }
    .page-scroll{
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    .top{
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    .navbar-default{
      background: #000 none scroll 0% 0%;
      box-shadow: 0 1px .6em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      border: thin dotted #000000;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 30px 40px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 30px 40px;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      width:95%

    }
    .intro-section {
      background: #508148;  
      min-width: 500px;       
    }
    .menItmArro {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    .brand {
      font-family: 'Rochester', cursive;
      font-size: 26px;
     }
     p {           
       min-width: 200px;
       right: 30px;
       font-color: FFE;
       }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adrriver/512n7vqx/5/

Comment: What error are you getting?  Can you make a fiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Actually, there aren't any errors being thrown.  Also if while in firebug>HTML, I change the value of the nav class's display, then the element reappears intact.  Please see the question for the JSFiddle.  Thanks.

Comment: There is a lot of noise in your fiddle including all the easing plugin code and your css reset.  Can you make a fiddle that shows your problem in a more focused manner?  You should also note that jsfiddle can include jquery for you.

Comment: My apologies.  The link just above is to the bare-bones version with relevant js.